# Identifying group homomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I am struggling to know exactly how to go about working out and proving that a mapping function is a group homomorphism for a particular example.

I have found that in order for the mapping to be a homomorphism, we must satisfy the condition

$f(x*y)=f(x)*f(y)$, where $f:G\to H$ is the function and this must be true for all $x,y\in G$.

With this in mind, we shall look at a simple example and ask,

is this a group homomorphism: $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z, x\longmapsto -2x$?

Here, it is obvious that the group law is addition and so it can be easily proven:

$f(x+y)=-2(x+y)=-2x-2y=f(x)+f(y)$ and so it is a group homomorphism.

For the example which I am having trouble with, the mapping is defined as

$g:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb R^*, x\longmapsto 2^{x^2}$.

The bit I am struggling with is knowing which group law to apply my test on since $\mathbb Z$ has the group law of addition whereas $\mathbb R^*$ has the group law of multiplication, so should it be addition or multiplication? Thanks!

Comment: My gut instinct is that it should be the group law of whatever the function is mapping from so in this case, it would be addition. If anyone could clarify I'd be grateful

Comment: I think that your notation in the definition is what is confusing you. Let's say that $(G, *)$ and $(H, \diamond)$ are the groups in question; then, we say that a function $\varphi : G \to H$ is a group homomorphism whenever $\varphi(g*h) = \varphi(g) \diamond \varphi(h)$ for all $g, h$ in $G.$

Comment: Particularly, $\varphi$ must map two things under the law of $G$ to their respective images under the law of $H.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely one of the hurdles in group theory! You can clarify the map by accompanying each set with the group operation: thus $g$ is the map
$$g:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
(\Bbb Z,+) & \rightarrow & (\Bbb R^*,\cdot) \\
x & \mapsto & 2^{x^2}
\end{array}\right.$$
Therefore you want to check if
$$\forall x,y\in\Bbb Z,\quad g(x+y)=g(x)\cdot g(y).$$
Notice how the symbol for the operation changes when going from inside the parentheses to outside.

Another remark: $(\Bbb R^*,+)$ is not a group, as it does not have a neutral element :)

Comment: So we are using both multiplication and addition in our proof! Thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: If I then wanted to show a counterexample, what numbers could I try? I thought maybe showing that $g(0)\neq 1$ but that does in fact work. Any ideas?

Comment: Notice that $g(x)\cdot g(y)=2^{x^2+y^2}$ and $g(x+y)=2^{(x+y)^2}$. Therefore, you want to find $x$ and $y$ such that $(x+y)^2\neq x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Would it suffice to set $x,y=1$ then? Since then we would show $g(x+y)=g(2)=2^{2^2}=2^4=16\neq g(1)\cdot g(1)=2\cdot 2=4$